# Nservice bus installation on Winserver 2012

Tags: msmq, nservicebus, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install nservice bus on a fresh win server 2012 box and things are not working properly. Any help is appreciated..

I get setup failed prematurely and when I dumped into log file.. this is the error I get..

Calling custom action NServiceBus.Wix.CustomActions!NServiceBus.Wix.CustomActions.CustomActions.InstallMsmq
Installing/Starting MSMQ if necessary.
CustomAction InstallMsmqAction returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 16:36:36: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action 16:36:36: Rollback. Rolling back action:

Do I have to manually add MSMQ features.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to enable the MSMQ features first.

BTW, the MSI is really only to be installed on developers machines, to prepare a machine in production use the powershell cmdlets, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/managing-nservicebus-using-powershell

Is your dev machine a WinServer 2012?

Comment: Yes that's our dev deployment server. I manually enabled msmq in server roles and msi installation went fine. I am a developer not an admin could you please let me know how do i get to that module Import-Module .\NServiceBus.Core.dll

Comment: If the msi installed correctly, you should now have a shortcut on the Start menu called "NServiceBus vX.Y.Z" and under that there is an option to launch pawershell called "NServiceBus Powershell Prompt".

Comment: Updated link to latest